# Reading Data from a file in Perl

Tags: perl

I have a file `abc.txt`  that has data of the form

```
sHost = "Arun";
sUid ="Abc";
```

I want to get `Arun` for `sHost` and so forth using Perl. My code:

```
my $filename = "abc.txt";

use strict;
use warnings;

open(my $fh, '<:encoding(UTF-8)', $filename)
  or die "Could not open file '$filename' $!";

while (my $row = <$fh>)
{
  chomp $row;
  if ($row=~m/sHost/)
  {
    print $row;
  }
}
```

The output I am getting `sHost = Arun;`

But I want only `'Arun'`. What logic should I apply here? I am very new to Perl and Linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the chomp, alter to this and the variable $host will contain the value

```
if ($row=~m/sHost = "(.*)"/) {
  $host=$1;
```

In simple terms the ( ) section is given to $1 if there is a match. See man perlre for the details

To generalise this to read any key and any value do something like this

```
 while (my $row = <$fh>) {
   if ($row = ~ /^(\w+) = "([^"]+)"/) {
     $value{$1} = $2;
   }
```

Then $value{'sHost'} will be "Arun" etc

Answer (score 1):

For universal config file parsing you can use following piece of code:

```
my %config;
if ($row =~ m/^\s*(["'`])?(\S+)\1?\s*=\s*(["'`])?(\S+?)\3?;?$/) {
    my $key       = $2;
    my $value     = $4;
    $config{$key} = $value;
}
```

This regexp allows you to process key-value lines with plain or surrounded by different quote type (**" ' `**, but you can add your symbols if you like) key/value with leading or/and trailing whitespaces, semicolon is not ogligatory. Also you can change *(\S+)* according to your requirements of key/value possible values (\S - all except whitespaces).

Answer (score 0):

use `m/.*=\s*([^\s]*)/g` instead of `m/sHost/`

use `print $1` instead of `print $row`

Answer (score -1):

Replace

```
if ($row=~m/sHost/)
```

with

```
if ($row=~s/sHost//)
```